# Creating Simple Parser in F#

Tags: parsing, f#, excel-dna, fsyacc, fslex

I am currently attempting to create an extremely simple parser in F# using FsLex and FsYacc. At first, the only functionality I am trying to achieve is allowing the program to take in a string that represents addition of integers and output a result. For example, I would want the parser to be able to take in "5 + 2" and output the string "7". I am only interested in string arguments and outputs because I would like to import the parser into Excel using Excel DNA once I extend the functionality to support more operations. However, I am currently struggling to get even this simple integer addition to work correctly.

My lexer.fsl file looks like:

```
{
module lexer
open System
open Microsoft.FSharp.Text.Lexing
open Parser

let lexeme = LexBuffer<_>.LexemeString

let ops = ["+", PLUS;] |> Map.ofList
}

let digit = ['0'-'9']
let operator = "+"
let integ = digit+

rule lang = parse
    | integ 
    {INT(Int32.Parse(lexeme lexbuf))}
    | operator 
    {ops.[lexeme lexbuf]}
```

My parser.fsy file looks like:

```
%{
open Program
%}

%token <int>INT
%token PLUS

%start input
%type <int> input

%%

input: 
    exp {$1}
;

exp: 
    | INT { $1 }
    | exp exp PLUS { $1 + $2 }
;
```

Additionally, I have a Program.fs file that acts like an (extremely small) AST:

```
module Program

type value = 
    | Int of int

type op = Plus
```

Finally, I have the file Main.fs that is supposed to test out the functionality of the interpreter (as well as import the function into Excel).

```
module Main

open ExcelDna.Integration
open System
open Program
open Parser

[<ExcelFunction(Description = "")>]
    let main () =
    let x = "5 + 2"
    let lexbuf = Microsoft.FSharp.Text.Lexing.LexBuffer<_>.FromString x
    let y = input lexer.lang lexbuf
    y
```

However, when I run this function, the parser doesn't work at all. When I build the project, the parser.fs and lexer.fs files are created correctly. I feel that there is something simple I am missing, but I have no idea how to make this function correctly.